# Is the following statement true

Tags: prime-numbers

Is the following statement true and how to prove it?
\begin{align}
(a^2)^{3N} \equiv  a^2 \mod{p} 
\end{align}

Comment: what is N? $N \epsilon N$ ?

Comment: for a general $N$, $a$ and $p$ this is most definitely not true

Comment: N & a are positive integers greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

A counter example: I assume that N is a generic natural number and p is any prime number.

Let's say $N=2 , p=7$
$a=2$

$$(2^2)^{3*2}=4096$$ and $$4096(mod7)=1$$

and $1\neq4(mod7)$
 a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Since $(a^2)^{3N}\neq a^2$ if $a\neq 1$, it is obvious that the statement cannot hold for arbitrary values of $p$. For example, taking any $p>(a^2)^{3N}$ will provide a counterexample.